# Server Manager in 2012 R2 - Volumes Missing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-volume

I have an network with around 12 servers running Windows Server 2012 R2. On the management server I have added all the others to the server manager console. When I go to "File and Storage Services" then "Volumes", it shows the volumes on each server's disks (cut off from screen clip):

[image]

Problem is, some servers are missing from the list. These are all VMs deployed from the same template, all get the same updates, etc, yet some servers show up in the volumes list and others don't. All are shown on the "All Servers" page in server manager.

I have tried logging into another server using a different admin account, in order to get a "clean" server manager, and added the same list of servers to it. When I go to Volumes the result is the same, some servers missing.

All of the disks are basic, no dynamics. There are a mixture of MBR and GPT, but that does not correlate to which are visible or not. I can use the Disk Management console to connect to any of the servers remotely and see their disks and volumes.